How to add a property received from trigger function to all logs in Azure Durable Function?
I am trying to implement a feature onto a .NET 6 durable function orchestration that has a service bus trigger. The feature is to add a correlationId to all logs and this correlationId will be coming from the message received in the service bus trigger.  I am trying to find the best way to implement this feature. I believe I am on the right track but I am hitting some issues.
The most brute-force way would be to pass correlationId to every orchestration, activity, and method that requires this correlationId, and then use log scopes. I want to prevent this as much as possible and so I am looking for alternative solutions.
The solution that I have come up with for now works partially. I have broken the problem into two parts, first being adding the property to the logs, and the second being saving the correlationId across the orchestration.
First, when it comes to adding the property to all logs, I have taken the use of ITelemetryInitializer. This lets me intercept ever log and add the correlationId property.
Note: You will see in the next code block where CorrelationIdContext.CorrelationId.Value is coming from
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;

namespace MyProject.Telemetry
{
    public class CorrelationIdAppender : ITelemetryInitializer
    {
        public void Initialize(ITelemetry log)
        {
            if (log is ISupportProperties logWithProperties)
            {
                if (CorrelationIdContext.CorrelationId?.Value is not null)
                    logWithProperties.Properties["prop_CorrelationId"] = CorrelationIdContext.CorrelationId.Value;
            }
        }
    }

Second, which is the main issue I have, is how to actually hold this correlationId throughout the orchestration. At first I thought that I can just create a static class with a string property, but even with my limited understanding of concurrency, threading, etc. I had a feeling this would cause issues. I did some research and found this article : https://engineering.payoneer.com/how-to-use-asynclocal-for-cross-service-logging-5a6d75dfeb81 which mentioned that AsyncLocal can be used to hold the correlationId. I have implemented this in the following.
using System.Threading;

namespace MyProject.Telemetry
{
    public static class CorrelationIdContext
    {
        public static AsyncLocal<string> CorrelationId { get; private set; }

        public static void SetCorrelationId(string correlationId)
        {
            CorrelationId ??= new AsyncLocal<string>();

            CorrelationId.Value = correlationId;
        }
    }
}

The problem with the approach I have taken is that it seems like the correlationId is only stored for logs that execute in the trigger. In the trigger which is where I receive the correlationId, I set the value in CorrelationIdContext by doing CorrelationIdContext.SetCorrelationId(queueItem.CorrelationId).
But even though the class is static when it goes to the orchestrator this value disappears.
Based on this do you have any suggestions as to what I can do to persist the correltaionId across the orchestration?


The feature is to add a correlationId to all logs and this correlationId will be coming from the message received in the service bus trigger. I am trying to find the best way to implement this feature.

The implementation by using AsyncLocal<string> is suitable for holding the correlationId in an asynchronous context. However, you need to make sure that this context is accessible and maintained across function invocations within the orchestration.

In Service Bus trigger function, ensure that you're correctly capturing the correlationId from the incoming message and setting it in the CorrelationIdContext like below code:

public async Task RunServiceBusTrigger(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("myQueue")] string message,
    ILogger logger)
{
    // Extract correlationId from the message or wherever it's stored
    string correlationId = GetCorrelationIdFromMessage(message);

    // Set the correlationId in the context
    CorrelationIdContext.SetCorrelationId(correlationId);

    // Start the orchestration
    string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("MyOrchestration", input: null);

    logger.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");
}


Ensure that accessing the CorrelationId from the CorrelationIdContext within the orchestration function and any activities called within the orchestration.

CorrelationIdContext.cs:
public static class CorrelationIdContext
{
    private static readonly AsyncLocal<string> _correlationId = new AsyncLocal<string>();

    public static string CorrelationId
    {
        get => _correlationId.Value;
        set => _correlationId.Value = value;
    }
}

Orchestration function:
[FunctionName("MyOrchestration")]
public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestration(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] DurableOrchestrationContextBase context)
{
    string correlationId = CorrelationIdContext.CorrelationId;

    // Now you can use this correlationId throughout the orchestration
    LogInformationWithCorrelationId(correlationId, "Orchestration started.");

    // Call activities passing the correlationId
    var result = await context.CallActivityAsync<List<string>>("MyActivity", null);

    return result;
}

[FunctionName("MyActivity")]
public static async Task<string> RunActivity(
    [ActivityTrigger] string input,
    ILogger logger)
{
    string correlationId = CorrelationIdContext.CorrelationId;

    // Use the correlationId in logging or any other logic
    LogInformationWithCorrelationId(correlationId, "Activity executed.");

    return "Activity result";
}


Make sure that your CorrelationIdContext is initialized correctly at the entry point of your function app.


Thank you Pavan for your response and giving me more insights to how AsyncLocal works. When I pass the correlationId to the orchestration and activity functions and set the value in the static class, I am seeing the value come in my logs. However I was trying to go for an approach where I would not have to pass the correlationId everywhere and maybe AsyncLocal is not the best approach. If you have any other ideas please feel to share as to how I can set the value once and have my logs pull from there without having to set the value multiple times. Thank you
